# Как обойти отсутствующий __contains в запросе django filter?

Tags: django

```python
class AGROUP(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

class REC(models.Model):
...
    agr_visible_for = models.ManyToManyField('AGROUP', blank=True, related_name='%(class)s_visible_for')
...
```

Надо сделать:

```
REC.objects.filter(agr_visible_for__contains=x)
```

где `x` - список или `qset` объектов `AGROUP`.

Проблема в том, что `__contains` в вариантах фильтрации не доступен. `__in` есть, просто `=` есть, а `__contains` нет.

Как можно это обойти?
Или как фильтровать по пересечению множеств?

Comment: А чем вас`__in` не устраивает?

Comment: тем, что __in - обратна требуемой :)
Нужно проверить, что искомый объект "содержит", а не "состоит в"